# Jade/Pug: не начинается новая строка после комментариев

Tags: html, jade, pug

После компиляции приведённого ниже Pug(Jade)-кода в выходном HTML-коде после комментариев не происходит переноса на новую строку:

```
// blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}
a.header-language-option(href='') Русский
// blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}
a.header-language-option(href='') English

<!-- blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}--><a href="" class="header-language-option">Русский</a>
<!-- blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}--><a href="" class="header-language-option">English</a>
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь закономерности, когда новая строка идёт после комментария, или это просто глюк?

([Онлайн-редактор для экспериментов](http://html2jade.org/))

Answer (score 2):

По дефолту Pug минифицирует скомпилированный HTML. Чтобы это предотвратить, в таске нужно указать `pretty: true`:

```
gulp.task('views', function buildHTML() {
  return gulp.src('views/*.pug')
  .pipe(pug({
    pretty: true;
  }))
});
```

Также я бы посоветовал убрать комментарии из компилируемого файла и оставить их только в Pug. Делается это так:

```
//- blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}
a.header-language-option(href='') Русский
//- blade: Замени ссылку　{{ route('route_pseudoname') }}
a.header-language-option(href='') English
```